# Multiple Memcached server /etc/init.d startup script that works?

Tags: centos, memcached, memcache

I install memcached server via source and can get standard start up script installed for 1 memcached server instance, but trying several scripts via google, can't find one that works to manager auto start up on boot for multiple memcached server instances. I've tried both these scripts and both don't work, service memcached start just returns to command prompt with no memcached server instances started

- lullabot.com/articles/installing-memcached-redhat-or-centos
- addmoremem.blogspot.com/2010/09/running-multiple-instances-of-memcached.html

However this bash script works but doesn't start up memcached instances at start up though ?

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$1" in
start)
/usr/local/bin/memcached -d -m 16 -p 11211 -u nobody
/usr/local/bin/memcached -d -m 16 -p 11212 -u nobody
;;
stop) killall memcached
;;
esac
```

OS: Centos 5.5 64bit
Memcached = v1.4.5
Memcache = v2.2.5

Anyone can point me to a working /etc/init.d/ startup script to manage multiple memcached servers ? Thanks

edit: Thanks mat, this is code that ended up working

```
#!/bin/sh
# chkconfig: - 80 12
# description:  The memcached daemon is a network memory cache service.
# processname: memcached
BIN=/usr/local/bin/memcached
USER=nobody
CON=2048
THREADS=4

$BIN -d -m 16 -p 11211 -c $CON -t $THREADS -u $USER
$BIN -d -m 16 -p 11212 -c $CON -t $THREADS -u $USER

case "$1" in
start)
$BIN -d -m 16 -p 11211 -c $CON -t $THREADS -u $USER
$BIN -d -m 16 -p 11212 -c $CON -t $THREADS -u $USER
;;
stop) killall $BIN
;;
esac
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add a service to chkconfig you will normally need a couple of special comments below the shebang of a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# chkconfig: - 55 45
# description:  The memcached daemon is a network memory cache service.
# processname: memcached
```

After adding the lines to /etc/init.d/memcached you can then issue

```
chkconfig --add memcached
```

There are of course additional run levels a process can start at so to check that you would issue

```
chkconfig --list | grep "memcached"
```

A common run level for memcached would be

```
chkconfig --level 345 memcached on
```

Comment: thanks mat i did try copying and pasting someone elses comments below the shebang of the script, but that didn't work. But copying and pasting yours did work! Code i ended up using for /etc/init.d/memcached which works on reboot/startup is edited above in original post. Not sure if syntax is correct but it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the script that I'm using to start multiple memcached instances. The key point is I use associative array to start all or just one specific instance:

```
#! /usr/local/bash4/bin/bash
#
# chkconfig: - 55 45
# description:  The memcached daemon is a network memory cache service.
# processname: memcached
# config: /etc/sysconfig/memcached

# Standard LSB functions
#. /lib/lsb/init-functions

# Source function library.
. /etc/init.d/functions

if [ -f /etc/sysconfig/memcached ];then 
    . /etc/sysconfig/memcached
fi

# Check that networking is up.
. /etc/sysconfig/network

if [ "$NETWORKING" = "no" ]
then
    exit 0
fi

typeset -A PIDS
typeset -A MEMORYS
typeset -A FACTORS
typeset -A INSTANCES

PORTS="11216 11217"
USER=memcached
basedir="/usr/local/memcached"
MAXCONN=1024
OPTIONS=""
INSTANCES=([11216]="session" [11217]="userdata")
PIDS=([11216]="$basedir/var/run/sohaphimdetails.pid" [11217]="$basedir/var/run/sohamuzik-top.pid")
MEMORYS=([11216]="1024" [11217]="2048")
FACTORS=([11216]="1.25" [11217]="1.125")

RETVAL=0
prog="memcached"
cmd="/usr/local/memcached/bin/memcached"
user="memcached"
ip="192.168.6.66"
peer="192.168.6.28"
max_conn=2048
max_memory=512
threads=8

function start()
{
    port="$1"
    if [ `ps -ef | grep "$cmd" | grep -c $port` -ge 1 ]; then
        action $"Starting the memcached server on port '$port'... " /bin/false
    else
        if [ ! -f $basedir/var/log/${INSTANCES[$port]}.log ]; then 
            touch $basedir/var/log/${INSTANCES[$port]}.log 
            /bin/chown memcached:memcached $basedir/var/log/${INSTANCES[$port]}.log
        fi
        $cmd -d -u $user -l $ip -c $max_conn -t $threads -m ${MEMORYS[$port]} -p $port -P $basedir/var/run/${INSTANCES[$port]}.pid -f ${FACTORS[$port]} -x $peer -X `expr $port '*' 10` -vv > $basedir/var/log/${INSTANCES[$port]}.log 2>&1
        action $"Starting the memcached server on port '$port'... " /bin/true
    fi
}

function stop()
{
    port="$1"
    if [ `ps -ef | grep "$cmd" | grep -c $port` -eq 0 ]; then
        action $"Stopping the memcached server on port '$port'... " /bin/false
    else
        kill -TERM `ps -ef | grep "$cmd" | grep $port | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }'`
        action $"Stopping the memcached server on port '$port'... " /bin/true 
    fi
}

case "$1" in
    start) 
        if [ -n "$2" ]; then
            start $2
        else
            for port in $PORTS; do
                start $port
            done
        fi
        ;;
    stop)   
        if [ -n "$2" ]; then
            port="$2"
            stop $port
        else
            killproc $prog
        fi
        ;;
    restart)
        if [ -n "$2" ]; then
            stop $2
            start $2
        else
            for port in $PORTS; do
                stop $port
                start $port
            done
        fi
        ;;
    *)
        printf 'Usage: %s {start|stop|restart} <port>\n' "$prog"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

PS: I used [repcached](http://repcached.lab.klab.org/) for replication.

Answer (score 0):

Since the script is working, I assume that it is not linked from /etc/rc.d, so it is not executed at startup. Assuming that your startup script is called /etc/init.d/memcached you should execute

```
chkconfig --add memcached
```

to add it to the list of scripts to be run at startup.

Comment: thanks i have already ran chkconfig --add memcached but still doing service memcached start results in no memcached servers started at all ?

Comment: Mat was more precise than me. Check runlevels with chkconfig and make sure that the script is executed in the right runlevels. If it is, check logs for error messages.